# animationend event is not firing using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, css

Using javascript I first generated the two img tags using javascript so the html becomes as below

```
<div id="imageContainer" class="mb-3">
<img src="/media/event_interact_images/LOC_6517.JPG" class="eventImage" width="360" height="270">
<img src="/media/event_interact_images/LOC_6377.JPG" class="eventImage" width="360" height="270">
</div>
```

The above is generated using the below javascript code snippet

```
displayImages() {
        //If the image container already exist, it must be deleted
        this.deleteExistingImageContainer();
        const imageContainer = document.createElement("div");
        imageContainer.id = 'imageContainer';
        imageContainer.className = "mb-3";

        //load all images
        for (var i = 0; i < this.displayImageUrl.length; i++) {
            const imageTag = document.createElement("img");
            imageTag.src = this.displayImageUrl[i];
            imageTag.className = 'eventImage'
            imageTag.setAttribute('width', 360);
            imageTag.setAttribute('height', 270);
            imageContainer.appendChild(imageTag)
        }
        this.cateringRequestCard.appendChild(imageContainer);
        var imageArray = imageContainer.getElementsByTagName("img");

        for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(imageArray[i]);
            imageArray[i].addEventListener('animationend', function (e) { console.log('animation ended'); }, false);
        };
    }
```

My problem is that the animationend event is not firing. Below is the css code. What have I missed?

```
.eventImage {
  position: absolute;
}

#imageContainer:nth-of-type(1) {
  border: 3px solid green;
  animation-name: fader;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  z-index: 20;
}

#imageContainer:nth-of-type(2) {
  z-index: 10;
}

#imageContainer:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fader {
  from {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

I am using Google Chrome ver. 113 browser

Comment: Your animation is for **imageContainer** but you are listening for it on the children images.

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely right the css code is targeting the wrong element. Will you write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by imvain2, the css code is pointing to the wrong element. The css selector `#imageContainer:nth-of-type(1)` means that we are selecting the first element with id `imageContainer` in the document. This is not what is the intension. The intension is to select the first `img` inside the `#imageContainer`. Therefore the css selector should have been

```
#imageContainer img:nth-of-type(1) {...}
```

Now the animationend event fires as expected.